# How to separate one column into two based on the criteria of other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a data frame like this:

```
Category <-c("Agriculture","Education","Education","Energy","Environment","Finance","Governance","Governance","Economics","Economics","Equality","Society" , "Protection","Trade","Trade","Trade", "Transport","Transport","Water")
Value <- c(0.00e+00, 8.75e+08, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 8.30e+08, 0.00e+00, 5.00e+08, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 3.50e+08, 0.00e+00, 2.20e+08, 3.00e+08, 0.00e+00, 5.06e+08,0.00e+00, 3.50e+08)
Prod_A <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA)
Prod_B <- c(NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3, NA, NA, 2, NA, 1)
df <- data.frame(Category, Value, Prod_A, Prod_B) 
df
 Category    Value     Prod_A    Prod_B
1  Agriculture 0.00e+00   NA     NA
2  Education 8.75e+08     NA      3
3  Education 0.00e+00     NA     NA
4  Energy 0.00e+00        NA     NA
5  Environment 0.00e+00   NA     NA
6  Finance 0.00e+00       NA     NA
7  Governance 8.30e+08    NA      2
8  Governance 0.00e+00    NA     NA
9  Economics 5.00e+08      1     NA
10 Economics 0.00e+00     NA     NA
11 Equality 0.00e+00      NA     NA
12 Society 3.50e+08       NA      1
13 Protection 0.00e+00    NA     NA
14 Trade 2.20e+08         NA      3
15 Trade 3.00e+08          2     NA
16 Trade 0.00e+00         NA     NA
17 Transport 5.06e+08     NA      2
18 Transport 0.00e+00     NA     NA
19 Water 3.50e+08         NA      1
```

Column 'Value' is the sum_value of either Product A or Product B.

'Prod_A' and 'Prod_B' are the numbers of products.

What I would like to do is separate the value of Product B from column 'Value' and make it a new column, so that the sum_value of these two products are not mixed together in one column. How can I achieve that?

I was using spread(df, Value, Prod_B) but it was apparently wrong...
Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: What do the values in `Prod_B / Prod_A` mean? Are they groups? Are there ever cases when `Prod_A/B` are both not `NA`? Right now we really need more information about the data to know how to best solve the problem

Comment: That being said, I THINK what you want is something like: `df$Value_B <- ifelse(!is.na(Prod_B), Value, NA)`

Comment: @MikeH. The values in Prod_A are the count of the products in product type A, same in Prod_B. It is a flat table, meaning in each row, column "Prod_A" and "Prod_B" won't have value at the same time. If there is a number of product count in "Prod_A", the corresponding value in "Value" represent the sum_value of "Prod_A" .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I think the `ifelse()` I posted above should be what you want then?

Comment: @MikeH. Thanks for the solution. But how could I remove "Value_B" from "Value", so that "Value" could be renamed to "Value_A".

Comment: I would just do something like we did for `Prod_B`: `df$Value_A <- ifelse(!is.na(df$Prod_A), df$Value, NA)`

Comment: @MikeH. Aha, yes! Sorry for the stupid question! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table, this should do the work:

```
# convert df to data.table if it is necesary:
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)

head(df)

      Category    Value Prod_A Prod_B
1: Agriculture 0.00e+00     NA     NA
2:   Education 8.75e+08     NA      3
3:  Governance 8.30e+08     NA      2
4:   Economics 5.00e+08      1     NA
5:       Trade 2.20e+08     NA      3
6:       Trade 3.00e+08      2     NA
# generate value_A and value_B as needed:

df <- df[is.na(Prod_A) & !is.na(Prod_B), value_B := Value,][is.na(Prod_B) & !is.na(Prod_A), value_A:=Value]

head(df)

       Category    Value Prod_A Prod_B  value_B value_A
1: Agriculture 0.00e+00     NA     NA       NA      NA
2:   Education 8.75e+08     NA      3 8.75e+08      NA
3:  Governance 8.30e+08     NA      2 8.30e+08      NA
4:   Economics 5.00e+08      1     NA       NA   5e+08
5:       Trade 2.20e+08     NA      3 2.20e+08      NA
6:       Trade 3.00e+08      2     NA       NA   3e+08
```

Please, note that the script asign value_A and value_B as 'NA' when Prod_A and Prod_B are 'NA'.